# Orbital mixing in square planar D4h complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, symmetry

Consider a square planar $\ce{ML4}$ complex with $D_\mathrm{4h}$ symmetry. Which orbital should the $\mathrm{a_{1g}}$ SALC of the ligands mix with, $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ or $\mathrm{4s}$? Both of those AOs transform as  $\mathrm{A_{1g}}$.

Comment: Why can't all three orbitals mix?

Comment: Could you refresh my memory in the meaning of SALC?

Comment: Symmetry adapted linear combinations.

Comment: How should I draw the MO diagram if all three mix together?

Answer (score 3):

***All*** orbitals of the same symmetry will interact (mix) to some degree.

So the ligand SALC will interact with both $\mathrm{a_{1g}}$ orbitals on the metal. The degree of interaction will depend on how close in energy the ligand $\mathrm{a_{1g}}$ is to the $\mathrm{4s}$ or $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbitals on the metal.

Generally, the ligand orbitals are closer in energy to the $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbital than to the $\mathrm{4s}$.